# How to display a variable that changes (like a number) within an html page?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say i have a simple page that just contains a button that when clicked adds 1 to a java script num variable:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div>
<button type="button" onclick="someFunction()">Clicking here adds 1 to the "count" variable</button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var count = new num;

someFunction() {
    count =+ 1;
}
```

So my question is what would you put into the js to display the "count" varible in the div with the id "output"? do you use innerHTML? Because that doesn't seem to work....

Also, is it possible with or without jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? However, you have to note that number increment must be done with `count += 1` or shorter `count++`. In the following example I have used prefix increment to do the calculation before assignment.

```
var count = 0;
function someFunction() {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = ++count;
}
```

Additionally, consider initialising numeric variables with its' initial values as described above.

Comment: just tried it and it worked. i see where i screwed up...i didnt tell it to show the variable correctly.